# Direct and Indirect Gap in Semiconductors for Optics

Tags: semiconductor-physics, laser, electronic-band-theory, optics

As far as I know, a semiconductor can be used to build a laser only if it has a direct energy gap. In this case, in fact, the transition between the conductive band and the valence band is allowed and quite easy, therefore making the decay by stimulated emission quite probable. On the other, in an indirect gap semiconductor this kind of transition requires more complicated mechanism with a lower probability, therefore making this kind of semiconductors not adequate for a laser.

Here comes my question: **is there a way to change the band gap of a semiconductor (from direct to indirect or the other way)? How?**
In particular, I would like to know if this can be done permanently (by engineering the bands, for instance) or momentarily (for instance, applying an electric field,...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify: Every semiconductor has a direct band gap **and** an indirect band gap, but in general they have different gap sizes. The smaller gap then dictates the materials behavior.

Band gaps can be changed in many ways. For example by heating/cooling, pressure or doping. For the semiconductor to change its behavior from indirect to direct you would have to lower the direct band gap and/or increase the indirect band gap until the direct band gap is the smaller one. In general this is possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for not being precise! Could you please edit your answer adding some examples or ways of doing it? I am quite confused...

Comment: I would say that major band gap engineering is highly impractical - if you need a different band gap use a different semiconductor.

Comment: @JonCuster My question (and also Nikl's answer, I suppose) is about how to change kind (direct or indirect) of semiconductor in the semiconductor itself, not by engineering a certain band gap but just switching from one kind to the other

Comment: Well to switch from one kind to the other you would have to engineer the band gaps and as @JonCuster said that is highly impractlcal and I do not have an example for it. If this kind of manipulation of band gaps would be that easy, there wouln't be any problem with Laser diodes.

Comment: @Nikl OK, thank you, the part about "heating/cooling, pressure or doping" made me think that this was easy!

Comment: It is easy to change the band structure in general, all you have to do is change the latice constant. But that doesn't mean it is easy to switch between direkt and indirect. It only means that it is possible at all. I am sorry for the confusion.